# Range Sum confusion with the range. Index and prefix sum mix up

Tags: c++

Given is an integer field `a` of size `n` and an integer `m`. `m` represents a number of queries. In each query one must find the sum of all elements from `l` up to and including `r`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    vector <long long>v(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        v[i] = v[i] + v[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int l, r;
        cin >> l;
        cin >> r;
        cout << v[r - 1] - v[l];
    }
}
```

How can I specify the range from the left?

Comment: i dont undstand what you are asking, but `v[i]=v[i]+v[i-1];` is wrong when the loop starts at `i=0`. Your code has undefined behavior

Comment: @saturdayAfternoon What should be the result if for example r >= n or r < l?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    size_t n;

    if ( std::cin >> n && n != 0 )
    {
        std::vector<int> v( n );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            std::cin >> v[i];
        }
 
        size_t m;

        std::cin >> m;

        while ( m-- )
        {
           size_t l, r;
       
           std::cin >> l >> r;

           if ( n <= r ) r = n - 1;
     
           if ( not ( r < l ) )
           {  
               long long int sum = 0;
               do
               {
                   sum += v[l];
               } while ( l++ < r );

               std::cout << "sum = " << sum << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

The program will be more clear if to add prompts before entering data. I hope you can do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning part of the code, you implemented everything correctly.

But, when it comes to the evaluation part, you have some misunderstandings.

You need to build sums in a loop, running m times, read everytime l and r and show the results.

Without doing any checks (which is dangerous), you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    vector <long long>v(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {

        int l, r;
        cin >> l;
        cin >> r;

        long long sum = 0;
        for (int index = l; index <= r; ++index) {
            sum += v.at(index);
        }
        cout << sum << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We can make the code a little more robust by doing range checks.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    if ((std::cin >> n >> m) and (m > 0) and (n > 0)) {
        std::vector <long long>v(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cin >> v[i];
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {

            int l, r;
            if ((std::cin >> l >> r) and (l >= 0) and (r < n) and (l <= r)) {

                long long sum = 0;
                for (int index = l; index <= r; ++index) {
                    sum += v.at(index);
                }
                std::cout << sum << '\n';
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

And wit better variable names:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int arraySize{}, numberOfQueries{};
    if ((std::cin >> arraySize >> numberOfQueries) and (numberOfQueries > 0) and (arraySize > 0)) {
        std::vector <long long>  arrayValue(arraySize);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            std::cin >> arrayValue[i];
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfQueries; k++) {

            int leftBorder{}, rightBorder{};
            if ((std::cin >> leftBorder >> rightBorder) and (leftBorder >= 0) and (rightBorder < arraySize) and (leftBorder <= rightBorder)) {

                long long sum = 0;
                for (int index = leftBorder; index <= rightBorder; ++index) {
                    sum += arrayValue.at(index);
                }
                std::cout << sum << '\n';
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the index issue in your code aside for now: for all `i`, `v[i]` contains the sum of all items between index `0` and index `i` (included). This means
`sum(l to r) = sum(0 to r) - sum(0 to l-1) = v[r] - v[l - 1]`

Back to the index issue. There are multiple places where we call `v[i-1]` or `v[l-1]`, meaning we may try to access `v[-1]`, which is incorrect.
You can address this with an `if` but for this very case, I prefer shifting everything by 1.

- `v` will contain `1 + n` elements.
- Contrary to C++ usage, loops will work with `i = 1; i <= n`
- With this right shift, the above formula becomes `sum(<original l> to <original r>) = sum(1 to r + 1) - sum(1 to l) = sum(0 to r + 1) - sum(0 to l) = v[r + 1] - v[l]`.
  Note that the value in `v[0]` does not matter, the formula stays true regardless (`v[0]` will stay equal to `0` anyway because that is what the constructor of `std::vector<long long>` does but I wanted to mention it).

Here is your code with minimal alteration, except for some input control and additional text shown on screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int itemCount, queryCount;
    std::cout << "How many elements do you want? ";
    std::cin >> itemCount;
    std::cout << "How many queries do you intend to do? ";
    std::cin >> queryCount;
//We waste the first index of v so that we guarantee we never call v[-1]
    std::vector <long long>v(1 + itemCount);

    std::cout << "Please type " << itemCount << " integers, pressing Enter between each." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= itemCount; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= itemCount; ++i) {

        v[i] = v[i] + v[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < queryCount; i++) {
        int l, r;
        std::cout << "Type an index between 0 and " << (itemCount - 1) << " ";
        std::cin >> l;
        std::cout << "Type an index between " << l << " and " << (itemCount - 1) << " ";
        std::cin >> r;
        if (0 <= l && l <= r && r < itemCount)
            std::cout << "Sum from index " << l << " to index " << r << ": " << v[r + 1] - v[l] << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Please ensure both indexes are between 0 and " << (itemCount - 1) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Bonus: if you consider indexes from `1` to `n` are more natural, when asking user input, than indexes from `0` to `n-1`, you can change the last loop to take that input. It actually makes it more simple since the conversion disappears.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < queryCount; i++) {
        int l, r;
        std::cout << "Type an index between 1 and " << itemCount << " ";
        std::cin >> l;
        std::cout << "Type an index between " << l << " and " << itemCount << " ";
        std::cin >> r;
        if (0 < l && l <= r && r <= itemCount)
            std::cout << "Sum from index " << l << " to index " << r << ": " << v[r] - v[l - 1] << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Please ensure both indexes are between 1 and " << itemCount << std::endl;
    }
```